# How I can have INSTEAD OF INSERT and AFTER INSERT inside the same trigger? (sql server)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

Is possible have INSTEAD INSERT and AFTER INSERT inside the same trigger?

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgInsertCompare
   ON  trigger_insert_teste
   INSTEAD OF INSERT
    AS
        DECLARE @testeID2 int
        SET @testeID2 = (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM trigger_insert_teste ORDER BY id DESC)
        PRINT(@testeID2)
    GO

    AFTER INSERT
    AS
    BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @testeID int
    SET @testeID = (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM trigger_insert_teste ORDER BY id DESC)
    PRINT(@testeID)
    END
    GO
```

Using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: This question is written so we can't really help you. Please include code that is not so genral as to be meaningless. I can think of no circumstance where I would want to do an instead of and an after for the same table.  But from your expample, I fear you are writing a trigger designed to handle only one record at a time which is a sql antipattern and can cause data integrity issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, but why would you need to? If you're controlling the insertion yourself (using `INSTEAD OF`), you should be able to add the `AFTER INSERT` code to the end.

Comment: @robinson I need get the ID before insert in the table, and then I need the new ID insert inside a table, did you undertand?

Comment: @soamazing: Your code above never performs an insert. How you do that (whether it's a manual ID or an identity/default id) should be simple to figure out if you can provide a more meaningful example.